# How can I fetch a single file at at a specific commit (by hash) from a remote git repository?

Tags: git

I'd like to fetch a file at a commit from a remote git repository without fetching all objects in the repository. I know `git archive` doesn't work as it can only fetch the tip of a branch.

With sparse-checkout and using protocol v2 (thanks @bk2204) I can create a work-tree with only the readme at a commit, but git transmits 10s of thousands of objects and 188mb.

```
mkdir linux
cd linux
git init
git config core.sparseCheckout true
git config protocol.version 2
git remote add origin git@github.com:torvalds/linux.git
echo "/README" > .git/info/sparse-checkout
git fetch --depth 1 origin ab02b61f24c76b1659086fcc8b00cbeeb6e95ac7
git checkout ab02b61f24c76b1659086fcc8b00cbeeb6e95ac7
```

```
remote: Enumerating objects: 71432, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (71432/71432), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (66651/66651), done.
remote: Total 71432 (delta 5277), reused 25451 (delta 3920), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (71432/71432), 188.85 MiB | 7.71 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (5277/5277), done.
```

Ideally this operation should fetch 3 objects
 - the commit (the known sha) > the commit's tree > the file in the tree

```
$ git cat-file -p ab02b61f24c76b1659086fcc8b00cbeeb6e95ac7 | grep tree
tree f6760b0bf32bd3b9a760d6e895c7fb76cd9c2ef8
$ git cat-file -p f6760b0bf32bd3b9a760d6e895c7fb76cd9c2ef8 | grep README
100644 blob 669ac7c32292798644b21dbb5a0dc657125f444d    README
$ git cat-file -p 669ac7c32292798644b21dbb5a0dc657125f444d
```

Comment: probably `--depth 1` does not fetch the commit you are interested in. You can fetch all commits (without --depth) and then get the file. Fetching commits does not mean cloning. It only brings over the relevant git data.

Comment: Git's not an arbitrary-byte-range server. If you want an arbitrary-byte-range server for objects in a git repo, you can use any of the many repo-server products and use e.g. http requests to pick arbitrary files and even byte ranges out of those.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you cannot fetch individual objects without partial clone support.  The protocol doesn't allow it.  Sparse checkout doesn't prevent you from fetching all of the data, it just prevents you from checking it all out.

I'm not aware of any major Git hosting providers that have generally available partial clone support right now, although I suspect it will be coming soon.  The feature is still relatively experimental.

However, if you're using a remote that supports protocol v2, you can fetch a specific commit, even if you normally wouldn't be able to without protocol v2.  You can run `git config protocol.version 2` and then you'll be able to fetch individual commits by hash.  Doing that with a `--depth 1` would be the best you could do in this particular case.

Comment: I can't fetch commits from github even after setting protocol.version 2. No error message, but the command exits 1.

Comment: It definitely works for me, testing against `git/git`.  Are you sure you're trying to fetch a commit and not a tree or a blob?  Can you edit your question to show what happens when you try to do it, including the hash you're trying to fetch?

Comment: I was responding from my laptop last night, which has an old version of git, `2.7.4`. On my desktop with 2.25.0 I can fetch a commit with v2, but it still fetches 188mb. I'll edit my question with the protocol v2 output.

Comment: That's a reasonable amount of data to fetch for a Linux working tree.  Sparse checkout won't affect what's fetched, so 188 MB is reasonable, since the working tree is 900 MB.  There's unfortunately no way to fetch less.

Comment: Looks like I'll have to wait for remotes to support the `--filter` option. Or use a host-provided api.

Answer (score 1):

A hosting service is supposed to have APIs to download a file of a revision or retrieve its content. For example, Gitlab has [GET /projects/:id/repository/files/:file_path/raw](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html#get-raw-file-from-repository), and Github has [GET /repos/:owner/:repo/contents/:path](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-contents), and Gerrit has [GET /projects/{project-name}/commits/{commit-id}/files/{file-id}/content](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-projects.html#get-content-from-commit).

For a simple self-hosting repository, to fetch a random commit or object by `git fetch`, you could set `uploadpack.allowReachableSHA1InWant=true` or `uploadpack.allowAnySHA1InWant=true`. In most cases, they are false(by default) for safety and performance. For a self-hosting Gerrit, it has similar configuration options. I have no idea about a self-hosting Gitlab.

Comment: Using protocol v2 I can `fetch` a commit by hash but even with sparse checkout the remote sends back many objects. I think it's recursively expanding all references except the parent.

Comment: @everett1992 sparse checkout does not affect `git fetch`. If you already can fetch a commit by hash, then you can add `--depth 1` or `--depth 2` to fetch as few objects as possible. `--depth 2` is recommended if you want to generate or apply a patch.

Comment: I did use `fetch --depth 1`, check the example in the question. I'll guess that sparse checkout doesn't filter objects requested from the remote.

Comment: @everett1992 Yes, sparse checkout is a local step. It does not affect `git fetch`, and does not reduce the number of objects.